# How to retrieve document size without addSnapshotListener?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have the code that retrieving the size of document using `addSnapshotListener`.

I just know retrieve doc size using `addSnapshotListener` but don't know any other way.

```
firestore.collection("DemandHistory").addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
       @Override
       public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {

            if (queryDocumentSnapshots != null){
               int count = queryDocumentSnapshots.size();
            }
       }
});
```

I want to retrieve doc size without `addSnaphsotListener`, how to do it?

Comment: There is no way to get a document's size without downloading its actual data. But if you want to only download the data once, without a realtime listener, you can use the approach from Alex' answer.

Comment: thank you done <3 @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: nice to hear you again Puff @FrankvanPuffelen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have the code that retrieving the size of document using addSnapshotListener

Calling `.addSnapshotListener()` on a `CollectionReference` object means you want to get data in realtime. Calling `size()` method on a `QueryDocumentSnapshots` object it doesn't mean that you are getting the size of a document, you are getting the number of all documents that exist within your `DemandHistory` collection.

You don't need to worry regarding the size of a single document as long as you keep it below the maximum size which is 1 Megabyte. Please see more details in the official documentation regarding [Usage and limits](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas):

> Maximum size for a document:1 MiB (1,048,576 bytes)

If you don't want to get data in realtime, instead of adding a listener simply use a `get()` call as explained [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document).

If you want to know the size of a document, there is a library for that:

- https://github.com/alexmamo/FirestoreDocument-Android/tree/master/firestore-document